# How to add tooltip to td in a table

Tags: jquery, html

Can someone give me an example of adding a tooltip whenever I hover a `td` in a `table`.

The content of the tooltip must come from database records.

*Example:*

If I hover A name on a table.. the tooltip must display his/her information.

Comment: As @Shaz's answer demonstrates, jQuery (as you've tagged the question) isn't required for this.  The `title` element attribute should do the job just fine.  Unless you need more functionality from the tooltip?  As for the database access, that's all server-side and would be done however you normally do database access in this setup.

Answer (score 44):

Use the `title` attribute:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" title="John Smith lives in New York."> John Smith </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/GpU5f/

Answer (score 39):

You'll get a tooltip on hover if you add 'title="whatever"' to the `<td>`:

```
<tr><td title="whatever">hover here to see "whatever" in a tooltip</td>
```

Where the title content comes from is a different and perhaps more difficult story, but perhaps you can arrange for the program code that is providing the cell's innerText to do the same for the cell's `title=...`.

HTH

-- pete

Comment: This should be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    $test = "Test"
?>
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td title="<?php echo $test; ?>">Hi there</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: did you forget echo ?

Answer (score 6):

since the original question was tagged jquery and none of the examples mention this (however trivial), it's just a matter of

`$(tdSelector).attr('title', titleText);`

Answer (score 1):

What ever there in the title attribute display as tooltip.

```
<tr><td title="whatever">hover here to see "whatever" in a tooltip</td>
```

I am getting tooltip what ever getting from value in order.productTitle.

```
<td title="{{order.productTitle}}">{{order.productTitle}}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

In **angular.js** it can work like this:-

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="data in list">
<td  class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tableRoceMovement"data-original-title="{{data.value}}" title="{{data.value}}"data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.value}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: op isn't asking about angular. They are looking for a solution in either html or jquery via the tags.